# Best Way to convert XML to JSON in MarkLogic using XQuery?

Tags: json, xml, xquery, marklogic-9

I want to know what is the best way to convert XML to JSON in MarkLogic.

I use `json:transform-to-json`,  but it does not give the proper response. Also it slows the service response a lot.

My XML has attributes or you can say `search:search` response data.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what is not a "proper response" in what is returned by the `json:transform-to-json`? It would be helpful if you provided a small example of the XML and the desired JSON output.

Comment: Also, an example of the code that you are using when invoking `json:transform-to-json()` is helpful, in order to undertand what strategy and options are being applied (if any) or if you are relying upon default behavior.

Comment: i am using for  search:search response data. Which is XML.

Comment: You are trying to transform the `search:search` XML response into JSON with the `json:transform-to-json()` method, but you have not posted an example of the code that you are using (in order to demonstrate whether or not you are specifying the second optional parameter for that method) and you have not identified what you consider "the proper response". It would be helpful if you could provide an example of the code you are currently running, and more clearly explain what it is that you want the output to look like or what exactly in the JSON response is a problem or is missing.